# Persist checkbox state in plain JS after prompt

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a simple TODO app written in vanilla javascript. Here is the application:

[image: Step1]

Issue/Problem that I am having at this point is:

When I click New todo button **the existing checked state of the checkbox disappears.**

I am not sure how to persist the checkbox state after prompt window **OK** click. Please find the source code below.

[image: Step2]

```
 const classNames = {
  TODO_ITEM: 'todo-container',
  TODO_CHECKBOX: 'todo-checkbox',
  TODO_TEXT: 'todo-text',
  TODO_DELETE: 'todo-delete',
}

const checkbox = document.createElement( "input" ); 
checkbox.type = "checkbox" 
checkbox.id = classNames.TODO_CHECKBOX 

const list = document.getElementById('todo-list')
const itemCountSpan = document.getElementById('item-count')
const uncheckedCountSpan = document.getElementById('unchecked-count')

function newTodo() {
  let newTodo = prompt("Please enter a todo item");
  if(newTodo){ 
    itemCountSpan.innerHTML = parseInt(itemCountSpan.innerHTML) + 1
    list.append(checkbox)
    list.innerHTML += "<li>" + newTodo 
  }

  let allCheckBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[id='todo-checkbox']");
  uncheckedCountSpan.innerHTML = allCheckBoxes.length
  console.log(allCheckBoxes.length)


  for(let i = 0; i < allCheckBoxes.length; i++){
  allCheckBoxes[i].onclick = function() {
    if ( this.checked ) {
      uncheckedCountSpan.innerHTML = parseInt(uncheckedCountSpan.innerHTML) - 1
    } 
    else {
      uncheckedCountSpan.innerHTML = parseInt(uncheckedCountSpan.innerHTML) + 1
    }
  };
  }
}
```

Please let me know if you have any thoughts/directions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues: first, you're appending the same checkbox every time. Second, you are directly editing innerHTML, which is forcing the DOM to re-render everything, reverting the state of the inputs. Here's how I would do it:

```
const classNames = {
  TODO_ITEM: 'todo-container',
  TODO_CHECKBOX: 'todo-checkbox',
  TODO_TEXT: 'todo-text',
  TODO_DELETE: 'todo-delete',
}

const list = document.getElementById('todo-list')
const itemCountSpan = document.getElementById('item-count')
const uncheckedCountSpan = document.getElementById('unchecked-count')

function newTodo() {
  let newTodo = prompt("Please enter a todo item");
  if(!newTodo){
    return
  }
  itemCountSpan.innerHTML = parseInt(itemCountSpan.innerHTML) + 1
  uncheckedCountSpan.innerHTML = parseInt(uncheckedCountSpan.innerHTML) + 1
  const checkbox = document.createElement( "input" ); 
  checkbox.onclick = function() {
    if ( this.checked ) {
      uncheckedCountSpan.innerHTML = parseInt(uncheckedCountSpan.innerHTML) - 1
    } 
    else {
      uncheckedCountSpan.innerHTML = parseInt(uncheckedCountSpan.innerHTML) + 1
    }
  };
  checkbox.type = "checkbox" 
  checkbox.class = classNames.TODO_CHECKBOX 
  list.append(checkbox)
  const listItem = document.createElement("li")
  listItem.innerHTML = newTodo
  list.append(listItem)
}
```

Note that I also replaced the `id` of the checkbox with a `class` - there are multiple checkboxes, and `id`s should be unique.